# Trying MultiThread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

I just wanted to try MultiThreading applications and check for how the performance would be if use multithread.

But I don't know either I did it wrong or I misunderstand it! I'm amateur or even beginner in Programming.

Because in Normal Mode(Without using Thread) it takes lower time to finish the process! for example:

With Using Thread: 02.8500253 But Without Using Thread: 02.5455425

Sometimes larger  difference!

my question is: Have I done it wrong or i misunderstood multithreading or etc. i wanted to know what's wrong? why without thread is faster here!?

Here's whole Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication57
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //    System.Windows.Forms.Timer mytimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
   //     mytimer.Interval = 1;
        sw.Reset();

        sw.Start();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myfunction));
        thread1.Start();
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myfunction));
        thread2.Start();

       // sw.Stop();
      //  for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++) 
     //   {
    //        listBox1.Items.Add(mylist[i]);
    //    }
        //listBox1.Items.Add
        //label1.Text = string.Format("Elapsed Time Using MultiThread= {0}", sw.Elapsed);

   //     mytimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    List<string> mylist = new List<string>();

    void myfunction()
    {    

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
        {
            mylist.Add(i.ToString());

     //       listBox1.Items.Add(i);
            if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                listBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { listBox1.Items.Add(i); }));
            }
            else { listBox1.Items.Add(i); }
        }
        if (mylist.Count == 20000)
        {
            sw.Stop();
            if (label1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label1.Text = string.Format("Elapsed Time Using MultiThread= {0}", sw.Elapsed); }));
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = string.Format("Elapsed Time Using MultiThread= {0}", sw.Elapsed);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();

        myfunction();
        myfunction();

        //sw.Stop();
    //    for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++)
    //    {
   //         listBox1.Items.Add(mylist[i]);
   //     }
        label1.Text = string.Format("Elapsed Time WITHOUT MultiThread= {0}", sw.Elapsed);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mylist.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Actually what you want to achieve?

Comment: I just wanted to check what's the difference between doing that test function (myfunction) with thread performance and without threads performance! but i Wondered because of being faster of single thread one!

Comment: Running more code (like `Invoke`) should take more time... What in particular surprises you?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I surprised because i thought using MultiThread would be much faster than single thread! but result was viceversa!

Comment: Calling `.Invoke(...)` pushes the delegate onto the UI thread. The rest of your code in `myfunction()` is extremely fast - so most of the work is happening on the UI thread anyway. So effectively you're running the same amount of work on the UI thread with both the thread and non-thread versions of your code. It's the overhead of starting new threads and calling `.Invoke` that takes longer. Threading is only useful if you are doing something computationally expensive on the non-UI thread(s).

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks so much!
I think i understood what's multithread use for!
for example when want to calculate somethings that is timetaking so much! right?

Comment: How can I know when threads finished their work!?
for example if I add items to listbox in button1click event! actually it does not do anything to listbox because that moment it want to add items from mylist, mylist is empty!
I don't know my question is clear of not?

Comment: There's a waitone function in UI thread https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, not sure whether this is the function you're looking for..

Comment: @ACE - When you create threads like you did then they will automatically clean up when they're done. If you want to let the UI thread know that the threads are done just invoke a method call on any UI control.

Comment: hmmmmmm I'm sorry! i think i didn't understand what you mean!
I have already used Invoke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multithreads does not necessarily run faster than a single thread, remember creating/scheduling threads takes many CPU cycles. For example, if you run your code in a single core CPU, multithreads actually makes it slower - although single core CPU is not common on modern PCs.

Adding 20000 strings into `mylist` takes only a few milliseconds, 99% of CPU time is spent on `listBox1.Invoke`.

In your code, you call `listBox1.Invoke` to marshal to the call to UI thread, so the code `listBox1.Items.Add(i);` from both threads is eventually running **on the same UI thread**, in this way there is no significant improvement (if any) over running on a single thread.

You can try this `listBox1.Items.AddRange(mylist)`, this is only called once, instead of 20000 times.

Comment: Thanks!
so how can i add items from mylist to listbox using multithread
as i commented in my post when i want to do it without invoke listbox does not get any item!

Comment: my CPU is: Core i7-2670QM 2.2Ghz

Comment: you can try this `istBox1.Items.AddRange(mylist)`, this is only called once, instead of 20000 times. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an example.

Comment: I just wondered at first i tried addrange in button click event! but i got no result!
but i tried it now again and i got the result :)

and the more exciting part was when i saw the stopwatch result! that was amazing! real faster with threads! like that!

Comment: but I'm not sure it gave me real time taken to get result or not!
I think it doesn't show me real time taken!

Comment: @ACE, you are a good learner. You mean the time is so fast that you don't believe? :)

Comment: thanks so much :)
but i just amazed for no reason actually! :( yes i thought it was so faster! but i checked again and i understood stopwatch show the time it reaches its code in click event! not the time it took after adding items to listbox!